# API Energylabel works from Postman, but not from my code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: Postman request is working, but code is not]

So I am having a headache here on this API call.
It definitely works correctly from Postman itself and gives me the right result.
Which means that my API key is correct.

However, I tried to build my call myself from React first, however, it didn't work at all.
Then I tried it with the code which Postman gave me as you can see on the right of the screenshot.
However, also if I use that code, it still doesn't work.
Also tested the "JavaScript fetch()" code from Postman in an individual file. Still no result.
It keeps telling me that the API key isn't valid, but it's the same API Key, so it should just work fine.

Also, it doesn't matter if I use the Cookie or not. If I leave it out of the code, it still doesn't work.
( Ofcourse I masked the API KEY itself in the screenshot's code... )

Do I miss something here?

[image]

Comment: Are you getting a CORS error by any chance?

Comment: No, I don't get any CORS errors. Even if I try it in an individual file on my host.
Here you can find it: https://smart-wise.nl/projects/react/energiecheck/extra/

In the console you can find the API Call error.

Comment: "*No, I don't get any CORS errors.*" [then what is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3GiO.png)?

Comment: Thank you! That clears a lot..
The thing is, when I clicked the error, it says invalid API. That was what misconfused me probably and why I didn't look any further into detail. My bad.

Now, I can use API's without issues so far, however, it's not that I am an expert in CORS, because I didn't have to deal with this so far.
Can you point me in a direction? Client wise anything more I can do or is this on the server side? ( htaccess? )

Comment: Also, I can't find the CORS error in my browser developer tools. Network tab shows something different than yours. ( Cant paste screenshot in my comment, so I updated my post )

Comment: The [preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) is failing.

Comment: @robertklep Thank you. I will have a look into it. Never confronted with this kind of problems with using API's so far, but there needs to be a first time for everything, right?
Now I need to find out how I put this into a working concept.